# Perl find missing elements in one array present in another array

Tags: perl

I have two arrays of IP addresses, I want to scan them and produce a third array of items only that are present in @replyResults but not in @savedResults

```
@savedResults = ("5.6.7.8", "9.10.11.12", "13.14.15.16");
@replyResults = ("1.2.3.4", "5.6.7.8", "9.10.11.12", "13.14.15.16", "17.18.19.20");
```

Ie should produce

```
( "1.2.3.4", "17.18.19.20 )
```

Any ideas?  I'm afraid I couldn't make anything I found online solve this particular use case.

Thank you

Comment: Also [perlfaq4](https://metacpan.org/release/JESSE/perl-5.12.1/view/pod/perlfaq4.pod#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?)

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having?

Comment: @dawg: Why link to such a specific (and old!) version of the FAQ?

Comment: @DaveCross: Because that is the one I remembered that showed how to do set calcs with arrays.

Comment: @dawg: It's [still there in the latest version](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays?-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays?) :-)

Comment: @DaveCross: Well that is a better link!

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code solves your requirement:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @savedResults = ("5.6.7.8", "9.10.11.12", "13.14.15.16");
my @replyResults = ("1.2.3.4", "5.6.7.8", "9.10.11.12", "13.14.15.16", "17.18.19.20");

# Build an auxiliary hash with the @savedResults items as keys.
my %saved_results_hash = map { $_=>1 } @savedResults;

# Filter the @replyResults array with keys that doesn't exist at hash
my @result = grep { !exists $saved_results_hash{$_} } @replyResults;

# <- @result contains: 1.2.3.4, 17.18.19.20
```